# Is it possible to display a string at a fixed position while content changes in a console app?

Tags: c#, windows, console-application

Is it possible to display the value of a variable at a fixed position in a C# Windows console app, to have it visible while the content of the screen otherwise would have pushed every old value upwards and out of sight, to not print the values again and again on new lines?

I know of Curses, but would like to use any standard if it exists, and learn how to do it.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: See [Console.SetCursorPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Do you have any code that shows what you want with regard to a string changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Console.SetCursorPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=netframework-4.8) is the framework method required to position the caret in a specific point of your console windows. Of course setting a point then displaces all the following writes to the console starting from the new point, so, if you want to write something at precise position and then restart from the previous point then you need to handle also the position of the previous writes.

This is just an example to get you started

```
static void Main()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        if (x % 10 == 0)
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        else
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, x % 10);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        WriteStatusText("Printing line " + x);

        // Remove this comment to see it slowly 
        // Console.ReadLine();


    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}


static void WriteStatusText(string msg)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 10);
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

Keep in mind that setting the position outside the buffer area ([Console.BufferWidth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.bufferwidth?view=netframework-4.8) and Console.BufferHeight) defined for the console will trigger an exception